# State whether the string 010 belongs to the language denoted by each of the following regular expressions

Tags: regular-expressions

(a) $(\epsilon + 1)0^{*}1^*0$

Solution that I cant read properly:

$(\epsilon + 1)0^{*}1^*0$

$= (\epsilon + 1)$ [by def of union]

$= 0 \epsilon 0^{*}$ [by def of star]

$1 \epsilon 1^*$

$\epsilon 010 = 010$ [def of concatenation]

I don't get it. Could someone explain this please. For instance I don't get how $(\epsilon + 1)0^* 1^* 0 \in (\epsilon + 1)$

---

My attempt without the solution was

$(\epsilon + 1)0^{*}1^*0$

$\equiv (\epsilon + 1)(1^{*})0^*0$ [Associativity of Concatenation]

$\equiv 1^{*}0^*0$ [Equivalence rule i.e $((\epsilon + R)R^{*}) \equiv R^{*}$]

$\equiv 0^{*}1^{*}0 \in 010$ [Associativity and equivalence rule]

Would that be right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution
(that you couldn't read)
*is* wrong,
sing all strings
have to end in $0$.

What the problem asks
is to show that
$010$
can be generated by
$(\epsilon + 1)0^{*}1^*0
$.

I would do this by stating
$\epsilon \in \{\epsilon+1\}$,
$0 \in \{0^*\}$,
$1 \in \{1^*\}$,
and
$0 \in \{0\}$,
and then
concatenating these.